# Docusign swift intergration

Tags: ios, swift, docusignapi

I am building a mobile app that requires some waivers for to be signed. Now I decided to go through Docusign in order to get electronic signatures but the do not seem to have any SDKs or tutorials for integration using swift language. Is there any way to integrate DocuSign with my app being completely composed of swift? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing in Swift you can use obj-C code. Use a bridging header to include obj-c code to your swift project. 
I don't know anything about Docusign, but if they have a obj-c SDK, you can use it in your project.

Comment: Thank You this helps a lot!!!

Comment: @GabeHollins Hollins Can u guide me, How to use DocuSign Sdk, I need my user signature in one my view controller. Is my user should register with Docusign?